# Rails wrap link_to on html code based on condition

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

Is there a clean syntax to wrap link_to on html code based on condition? Because DRY, I don't want to repeat the same code.

```
<% if condition? %>
  <%= link_to bla_bla_path do %>
    <p>Some html here</p>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <p>Some html here</p>
<% end %>
```

I know there is [link_to_if](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if) but it don't have the part `else` :(((

Comment: You can create a helper to keep it DRY. How `condition` will look like ?

Comment: Do you mean you don't need to use `else` or your just don't understand how to use it?

Comment: I want to use `else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `link_to_if` the block to pass is actually the `else`. Have a closer look at the documentation you linked to.

Anyway, using `link_to_if` won't solve your dryness issue either. What you want to do is using [capture](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-capture) to assign the common html to a variable:

```
<% content = capture do %>
  <p>Some html here</p>
<% end %>

<% if condition? %>
  <%= link_to bla_bla_path do %>
    <%= content %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= content %>
<% end %>
```